# html redirection to php

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have a HTML login page in which I have a radio button for admin and user and according to it if the user selects "admin" then it should redirect to admin login page and if he selects "user' then it should go to user login page.

the html login page is as given below:

```
<!-- THE LOG IN PAGE -->
<div id="id01" class="modal">  
    <form name="login" id="login" class="modal-content animate" action="login.php" method="post">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <label><b>Email Id:</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Id" name="email" id="email" required>
            <label><b>Password:</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required> 
            <label><b>User Type:</b></label>
            <table width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="usertype" id="usertype" value="admin" required>ADMIN</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="usertype" id="usertype" value="user" required>USER</td>
            </tr>
            </table>            
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
            <span class="psw"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) 
        {
            if (event.target == modal) 
            {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

the admin_login.php page for user is given below:

```
<?php
```

session_start();

$email=$_POST["email"];

$psw=$_POST["psw"];

$name="";

include 'db_config.php';

$sql="SELECT name,password,email FROM admin_details where email='$email'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)

{

```
// output data of each row

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 

{

    $name=$row['name'];

    if($psw == $row['password'])

    {

        $_SESSION['name']=$name;    

        $_SESSION['email']=$email;  

        header('Location: admin_index.php');

    }   

    else

    {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 

        echo 'alert("WRONG PASSWORD ENTRY. TRY LOGGING IN AGAIN !!!" );'; 

        echo 'window.location.href = "admin_index.php";';

        echo '</script>';           

    }

}
```

}

else

{

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

echo 'alert("You must REGISTER first and then LOGIN !!!" );'; 

echo 'window.location.href = "admin_index.php";';

echo '</script>';
```

}

$conn->close();

?>

Comment: where is your php script used for redirection?

Comment: There are two ways, either using Javascript or PHP(Get the element value, compare and redirect accordingly)

Comment: Man, that's painful on the eyes... Try throwing it through an online formatter or something, please. This one is pretty decent I think http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Comment: I had tried using javascript but was not successful

Comment: Much less like chunk's confession from The Goonies, thanks! https://youtu.be/Q5UG7ISJfP0

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that. check for type of user and `redirect` accodingly

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
   // your code to check email id and password
    if($_POST['usertype'] == 'admin'){
        header('Location: admin.php');          
    }elseif($_POST['usertype'] == 'user'){
        header('Location: user.php');       
    }else{
        $error = "Invalid Login";           
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first, add and handler to your radio buttons:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="usertype" id="usertype" value="admin" required>ADMIN</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="usertype" id="usertype" value="user" required>USER</td>
```

to

```
<td><input type="radio" name="usertype" id="usertype" onclick="handleUserTypeChanges(this);" value="admin" required>ADMIN</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="usertype" id="usertype" onclick="handleUserTypeChanges(this);" value="user" required>USER</td>
```

Then you could use some js like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleUserTypeChanges(radioButton){
        var form = document.getElementById("login");
        var userType = radioButton.value;

        if (userType == 'admin') {
            form.action = 'your/path/to/admin/page/admin.php';
        }else{
            form.action = 'your/path/to/user/page/user.php';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i dont know why but the code is not working in my case

Comment: I have edited my question and inserted the admin_login.php page for admin.Is there any issue in the admin_login.php page?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on login.php file, hope it will help.

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{

if($_POST['usertype']=='admin') header('location: admin.php');
else if($_POST['usertype']=='user') header('location: user.php');
exit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done few changes in your while loop. hope so it will solve your problem.

you can select role of user that is admin or user. on the behave of user role you can navigate the user to admin page or login page.
here in database you add another attribute and insert the role if user select the admin radio button then set 1 in role attribute and if user select the user radio button the set 2 in role attribute.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 

{

    $name=$row['name'];
$psw = $row['password'];
$role =$row['role']; 
    if($psw == $row['password'])

    {

        $_SESSION['name']=$name;    

        $_SESSION['email']=$email;  
if($role == 1){
        header('Location: admin_index.php');
}
if($role == 2){
        header('Location: admin_index.php');
}

    }   

    else

    {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 

        echo 'alert("WRONG PASSWORD ENTRY. TRY LOGGING IN AGAIN !!!" );'; 

        echo 'window.location.href = "admin_index.php";';

        echo '</script>';           

    }

}
```